# TypeError: "name" is read-only ,when trying to update the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, updating

I use this handleDepartmentChange to change the input value when updating.

```
  const handleDepartmentChange = (companyIndex, departmentIndex, e) => {
    const newCompanies = [...companies];
    newCompanies[companyIndex].children[departmentIndex].name = e.target.value;
    console.log(newCompanies[companyIndex].children[departmentIndex].name);
    setCompanies(newCompanies);
  };
```

For that I use the following way

````
 <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                  <input
                    style={{ width: "410px" }}
                    type="text"
                    //defaultValue={department.name}
                    value={department.name}
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      handleDepartmentChange(companyIndex, departmentIndex, e)
                    }
                  />
                </div>
    ```
but this dont allow me to chage the value of department it say its read only property? why? is there any other method or way around to fix this Issue?
````

Answer (score 0):

- This is happening because of you have written something like this in
  your Input tag.

  **value={department.name}**
- Input tag value attribute make the value fix for that attribute. You
  can't change the value of that input after giving attribute value.
  After that you will unable to write anything in that input field.
- **So remove the value attribute.**
- To fix this you can go for default value as you have mentioned in
  your tag. Default value allows to modify input field's value.

  **defaultValue={department.name}**
- May be It will solve your issue...Let me know if not...Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Although I can now edit the name, its not updating. sill gives me a error as 'ncaught TypeError: 0 is read-only'

Answer (score -2):

The error message "read-only property" indicates that the `department` object you are trying to modify is defined as a read-only property in your code. This can happen for various reasons, such as if the `department` object was passed down as a prop from a parent component and is not intended to be modified by the current component.

To fix this issue, you can create a copy of the `department` object in your `handleDepartmentChange` function before modifying it. Here's an updated version of your function:

```
const handleDepartmentChange = (companyIndex, departmentIndex, e) => {
  const newCompanies = [...companies];
  const newDepartment = { ...newCompanies[companyIndex].children[departmentIndex] };
  newDepartment.name = e.target.value;
  newCompanies[companyIndex].children[departmentIndex] = newDepartment;
  console.log(newDepartment.name);
  setCompanies(newCompanies);
};
```

This should allow you to modify the `name` property of the `department` object without encountering read-only errors.
I hope this help.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. It looks like it's been a while since you've posted and may not be aware of the latest policies since your three answers today appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As a heads-up, [posting of AI-generated content is not permitted on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

Comment: If you used an AI tool for assistance on this answer, could I ask you to (1) Reply in a comment here confirming that it was AI-generated, along with what tool (e.g., ChatGPT, Bing Chat, Copilot, etc.) -- We're compiling data on AI-assisted answers and could use your help. (2) After commenting, I recommend deleting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.